# Is there a way to avoid admob to shoy banner or insterstisial that has more than one ad inside?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have an android app with an admob banner in the main Activity.
I am in the was designed and approved for Families Program of Google Play
After more than a month being in production for the first time I made a small change in the text of the description of the app.

## After that I got an e-mail from Google Play, stating that there was a "Violation of Families Policy Requirements"

Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements
Apps that contain elements that appeal to children must comply with all Families Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:
Eligibility Issue
Ads & Monetization: Ad format requirements​
Only one ad placement can occur per page within your app.
For example, your app cannot contain a banner ad with multiple offers.

## To resolve this issue, please remove any additional ads displaying on each page within your app before submitting an app update. For more details, you can refer to the Ad format requirements section on the Ads and Monetization policy page.

Attached in the mail was the image I attach here, that was shoing that there appeared a banner with multiple ad inside, each one with a link to a different page.
I had seen in admob portal that one can block some specific ads based on the type of contente, but did not find a way to prevent admob to show these "multi-ads" formatted banners.
Is this a way to perform this programmatically or should I consider to stop using admob as ad network?
See this example of a [banner that violates policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh8du.png)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I could not find a way to avoid these type of ads. Finally what I did was to leave the Families Program of Google Play

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this doc and change the target audience setting based on your app content rating on Admob.**

1. Sign in to your AdMob account at https://apps.admob.com.
2. Click Blocking controls in the sidebar.
3. Click the Ad content rating tab.
4. Select the maximum ad content rating you want applied to your entire account. You should select the maximum ad content rating that’s suitable for your app users.

[Ads Targetig](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7562142?hl=en)

You can set programmatically also.

[Programatically Target Rating](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting)